# Can AWS Fargate scale automatically, like Lambda does?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate

Can AWS Fargate scale on demand like Lambda?
Suppose we set 10 container instances in scaling settings.

But what if certain times 10 instances is not enough, how do we scale further (11,12...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Fargate can scale on-demand.

You can actually use [target tracking scaling policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-autoscaling-targettracking.html) and configure scaling limits (i.e. instance/task count). You will also have to configure Service AutoDiscovery in order to distribute load on the new instances.

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html)

Answer (score 3):

Fargate supports [auto-scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/what-is-application-auto-scaling.html), you can enable this within your configuration.

You will need to set it to scale against a specific metric (such as average CPU or average network in).

By using auto scaling you can set scale-out (add more containers) and scale-in (remove containers) rules that will affect how many containers you need running at the same time.

There is more information regarding how to configure this available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-auto-scaling.html).